# Dynamic create parent-child relationship array based on another table field values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, parent-child

There are 2 arrays Say

```
1. Groups
$groups = array("user", "account", "client")
2. Results
$results = array(
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A1",
      "client"  => "C1" 
   ),
   1 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A2",
      "client"  => "C1" 
   ),
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A3",
      "client"  => "C1" 
   ),
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A2",
      "client"  => "C2" 
   ),
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A1",
      "client"  => "C4" 
   ),
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A1",
      "client"  => "C5" 
   ),
   0 => array(
      "user"    => "U1",
      "account" => "A2",
      "client"  => "C5" 
   )
) ;
```

I want following OUTPUT

```
$output = array(
   "U1" => array(
       "A1" => array(C1,C4,C5),
       "A2" => array(C1,C2,C5),
       "A3" => array(C1)
   )
);
```

The Groups array values are dynamic and may be any order. I want output in order the first value of groups array is the parent element of Output array and second value of group array is the child of parent Output array and so on.

Comment: Show what you've done so far... and You haven't specified that there are multiple users or not...

Comment: yupps there can be mutiple users.

Comment: Solution i tried is somewhat of patch type. I think recursion would help there but how, i don't know. Demo - https://eval.in/858234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using PHP greater or equal to 5.6. There we have [`...` (splat operator)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) that will come really handy:

```
$output = [];
array_map(function (...$keys) use (&$output) {
    // Pop the last key, because it is actually a value.
    $value = array_pop($keys);

    // Prepare "element" to assign the value to using keys and references.
    $element = &$output;
    while($key = array_shift($keys)) {
        if (!isset($element[$key])) {
            $element[$key] = [];
        }

        $element = &$element[$key];
    }

    $element[] = $value;
}, ...array_map(function ($group) use ($results) {
    return array_column($results, $group);
}, $groups));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f987f0e19012a94877920ba9bc8c827a80a2858).

In short, we take advantage of the ability of [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to take any number of arrays as arguments and traverse them kinda parallelly.

Comment: your code is helpful but i was unable to handle rest of information. please see this Link. https://eval.in/859744

Comment: Try, this [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab074921d194b6f028a09ac61804d139baf00f3f). Basically, we pass results to `array_map` along side columns and then assign item as the value.

Comment: @YogitaSharma, here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2be9157caaa2707e4eeaccffb001ddcf3ce56247) with your last data provided.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a foreach loop like this

```
$new = array();
foreach($results as $key=>$value){
  $new[$value["user"]][$value["account"]][] = $value["client"];
}
print_r($new);
```

live demo : https://eval.in/857969

Using `$groups` : https://eval.in/857970

```
$new = array();
foreach($results as $key=>$value){
  $new[$value[$groups[0]]][$value[$groups[1]]][] = $value[$groups[2]];
}
```

Example for multiple user's : https://eval.in/857973

Update

For dynamic groups array : You can use eval if you are not interacting user input here. : https://eval.in/858306

Comment: The final array keys are in the order from $groups array.

Comment: $groups array is dynamic array. it can be of any length and in any order.

Comment: Solution i tried is somewhat of patch type. I think recursion would help there but how, i don't know.

Comment: You can use eval if you are not interacting user input here. : eval.in/858306